# How to make a status(loading) showing form

Tags: c#, task

I am trying to display a modal window while retrieving a big data from a database. (I'm using C#.) The "retrieving data" part of the program is made with `async/await` function, and I call the function by:

```
GetSomeData(sqlquery, grdControl);
```

And this is where my problem starts, in the declaration of `GetSomeData`, I have put a line to popup a modal windows and because of this, it won't proceed to the next line.

```
private async Task GetSomeData(string sSQL, GridControl grd)
{
    LoadingForm frmload = new LoadingForm();
    frmload.ShowDialog();
    DataTable results = await GetDataSetAsync(sSQL);
    frmload.Close();
}
```

I've read threads about implementing the loading form by using a separate task or by using a background worker but if I use this, the loading form no longer looks like a modal form and I want the background form to be inactive thus preventing user interactions while loading.

Comment: you could instead of making the load form modal, just disable stuff in the original.

Comment: hmmm are you talking about modaless and disable every other thing in the background? that could be an alternative answer but not exactly looking as modal.

Comment: then the only other choice would be to do the actual get on the modal form......

Answer (score 0):

Do not load data from database in method where you want to show modal dialog.

You should move `DataTable results = await GetDataSetAsync(sSQL);` into your modal window.

You can pass DataTable results and sSQL to your modal window and perform Get there:

```
DataTable results;
LoadingForm frmload = new LoadingForm(results, sSQL);
frmload.ShowDialog();
// Your data should be ready here
```

Inside of LoadingForm:

```
results = await GetDataSetAsync(sSQL);
this.Close()
```

Comment: Wow this seems to resolve the problem. Pass SQL query strings to the modal and return DataTable to parent form when closing the modal. Great!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `WaitingForm<T>`, which will wait for a given `Task<T>` and close itself:

```
public partial class WaitingForm<T> : Form
{
    // ...

    Task<T> task;
    public Task<T> Task
    {
        get => task;

        set
        {
            task = value.ContinueWith((task) =>
            {
                Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { Close(); });
                return task.Result;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

You would use it as:

```
public static void Foo()
{ 
        var result = DoWithWaitingForm(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            return Task.FromResult(42);
        });

        var result2 = DoWithWaitingForm(() => Foo().Result);
    }

    // helper to deduce the type of the generic parameter for WaitingForm
    public static Task<T> DoWithWaitingForm<T>(Func<T> operation)
    {
        var form = new WaitingForm<T>
        {
            Task = Task.Run(operation),
        };
        form.ShowDialog();

        return form.Task;
    }

    // example async function
    async static Task<int> Foo()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            return Task.FromResult(42);
        });
    }
```